# Lateral Unnest -SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, unnest

Lateral Unnest -ing gives me a bit of a problem.

I have a table
That looks like:

```
Name  | Info
------|------
  A   | Info1, Info2, Info3
  B   | Info1, Info 2, Info3
```

I want it to look like is:

```
Name  | Info
------|------
 A    | Info1 
 A    | Info2 
 A    | Info3 
 B    | Info1 
 B    | Info2 
 B    | Info3
```

There's a few more columns in there. I want to all keep them. 
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `unnest()`:

```
select t.name, trim(i) as info
from t cross join lateral
     unnest(string_to_array(t.info, ',')) i;
```

You don't need to use `unnest()`, because you can split directly to an array:

```
select t.name, trim(i) as info
from t cross join lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(t.info, ',') i;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but it puts all the other columns in one column?
What if I want to keep the other columns in columns aswell?
Na . | CB|CC|Info
------|------|----|--
  A   | xyz|xyz|Info1, Info2, Info3
  B   | xyz|xyz|Info1, Info2, Info3

Na . | CB|CC|Info
------|------|----|--
 A    | xyz|xyz|Info1 
 A    | xyz|xyz|Info2 
 A    | xyz|xyz|Info3 
 B    | xyz|xyz|Info1 
 B    | xyz|xyz|Info2 
 B   | xyz|xyz|Info3

Comment: @somanyquestions you need to list the columns explicitly:  `select t.name, t.some_value, t.some_date, .... , trim(i) as info from ...`: https://rextester.com/KBWA21456

Comment: @somanyquestions . . . You would list the columns.  And, if that doesn't answer the question, then ask a *new* question.  This one is quite clearly about two specific columns.